# How to list a directory content

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

How to access directory files when we don't have index file.

I used this htaccess code but it worked when I mention file but I want to show directory file without insert index file.

Please check my htaccess code and tell me where i am wrong thanks

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ check.html?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: _"i want to show directory file"_ - What is a _"directory file"_? What output are you expecting? The above htaccess simply redirects any request that isn't a valid directory or file to `check.html` with the requested path as a querystring.

Comment: directory file means in my directory there are so many files and i want when open url then show files and folders which already in directory

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson please tell me how to solved that :(

Comment: So you want to list the directory contents?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes i know please tell me how to do that then

Comment: yes @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Did you try the `Options Indexes`?

Comment: yes i want to list  the directory contents

Comment: no i didn't used

Comment: will you please make htaccess file over my code in answer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Options` configuration option. The documentations presents `Options` by saying

> Configures what features are available in a particular directory

You can use many options, the one you are looking for is `Indexes`. To add this option you need the instruction `Options +Indexes`.

In an .htaccess file you can use it simply by putting this.

```
# Allows Apache to list the directory content
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ check.html?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In a vhost file it could be like this.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

I suggest to use this in your vhost file though.

> As said in comment it's recommanded to configure a site in a vhost file. If you can (if your host allows you), use the vhost instead of the .htaccess file. If you can set all your configuration in your vhost and avoid using .htaccess, you can use `AllowOverride None` to forbid the .htaccess usage then.

See the [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) and the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/core.html#options).

Comment: I would even recommend skipping the `.htaccess`-files all together and move all contents of `.htaccess` into the vhost. Then you can set `AllowOverride None`, which will speed up the requests.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I agree, it's recommanded to use a vhost instead of .htaccess. But some hosts allow `.htaccess` and not  vhost file.

Comment: ...true. I keep forgetting that people still uses shared hosts and such :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I usually forget it too, but the OP question was about an .htaccess so I have to write about .htaccess. But I've added a bit about the usage of vhost instead of .htaccess :)